# User specific data retrieval

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently making a project that requires me to be able to pull information off Firestore with data specific to a user.

At the moment I have the application creating a user and am able to read a specific table.

I was wondering is there any way to read and or save data specfic to a `UserID`?

```
public String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

I'm using this at the moment to read and save the userid to a document but was wondering what the most popular methods of  user-specific data retrieval is?

Would it be possible to set a document equal to a userid and retrieve it that way?

I'm just asking to see if there are multiple ways of doing this and whats the most popular. For some reason I am finding tutorials/documentation hard come by so even links to them would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, what is the specific problem you're running into?

Comment: How does the industry/community do user based data retrieval with android and Firestore?

Comment: It's up to you.  All data modeling in SQL databases should revolve around how you intend to query the data.  There is not a one right way to do it.

Comment: @AidanDoherty Will it be helpful if I'll show you two ways in which you can get the user data from the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes , that would be very helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> was wondering what the most popular methods of user-specific data retrieval is?

Assuming you have a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- uid
            |
            --- uid: "TheUidOfTheUser"
            |
            --- //other users details
```

A recommend way would be to use a `DocumentReference` like in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference uidRef = rootRef.collection("users").child(uid);
uidRef.get(/* ... */);
```

The second approach would be to use a `Query`, like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.whereEqualTo("uid", uid);
query.get(/* ... */);
```

In which the `uid` variable holds the value for the uid of the user that you are searching for.